Right way to allocate type instances containing pointers in Fortran
Consider the following minimal example:
module lib
    private
    type node
        integer::val
        type(node),allocatable::next
    end type
    type,public::list
        integer::num=0
        ! `first` should be a pointer to avoid making `this` a target in procedures.
        type(node),pointer::first=>null(),last=>null()
    contains
        procedure::add=>list_add
        final::list_final
    end type
    interface list
        procedure list_new
    end interface
contains
    function list_new()result(this)
        type(list)::this
        print*,'list_new'
        allocate(this%first)
        this%last=>this%first
    end
    subroutine list_add(this,val)
        class(list),intent(inout)::this
        integer,intent(in)::val
        print*,'list_add'
        this%num=this%num+1
        allocate(this%last%next)
        this%last=>this%last%next
        this%last%val=val
    end
    subroutine list_final(this)
        type(list),intent(inout)::this
        print*,'list_final'
        ! Checking if `first` is associated is necessary to avoid the error on
        ! finalization of uninitialized instances.
        if(associated(this%first))deallocate(this%first)
    end
end


program prog
    use lib
    type(list)::obj  ! type(list),allocatable::obj
    obj=list()  ! allocate(obj,source=list())
    call obj%add(42)
end

It is a naive implementation of a linked list using allocatable nodes. Due to some limitations in the original code, first should be a pointer, which is allocated in the constructor list_new. To avoid a memory leak, the final procedure list_final will automatically deallocate first, when an instance goes out of scope. But compiling this code (for example, with the GNU compiler gfortran-13.1.0 using the -g flag for debugging) and executing it will end with Fortran runtime error: Attempting to allocate already allocated variable 'this' at line allocate(this%last%next). Before this error the output is:
 list_new
 list_final
 list_final
 list_add

If I understand it correctly, list_final is called twice:

to finalize the instance created in the declaration at line type(list)::obj,
to finalize the instance created on the right at line obj=list() after copying its contents to obj.

The second call deallocates memory that is pointed to by first of list(), and causes obj%first to point to an invalid memory address, because the pointer was just copied in the assignment. So last%next (or first%next) seems to be already allocated in the first call of list_add.
Replacing type(list)::obj with type(list),allocatable::obj and obj=list() with allocate(obj,source=list()) fixes this issue and list_final is never called.
In my knowledge, this seems to be the only safe and clean way to allocate instances of a type (without redefinition of assignment and replacing final with an explicit call to a destructor). Even though obj=list() appears to be more elegant and is similar to instance-initialization expressions in other programming languages, it can cause unexpected behavior in Fortran (and also adds an additional copy operation).
Is allocate with source the only right way to initialize instances of such types?

To confirm/clarify your thinking: obj=list() indeed results in two finalizations. In this assignment list() is executed, then obj is finalized, then obj is defined, then the list result is finalized. (I'm not sure what you mean by "automatic allocation at line type(list)::obj", as obj is not an automatic object and it has no finalizable components.)

@francescalus my wording is probably incorrect. I compared the declaration of the type variables to allocatable vs. automatic arrays, i.e., type(list),allocatable::obj vs. type(list)::obj, and called the second case "automatic allocation". But, maybe, I should reformulate it.

Your reasoning about finalization and the cause of the runtime error being down to dangling pointers caused by finalization is correct. You're also correct to think that the way to handle this is by using defined assignment for obj=list(). Where your question gets really interesting is that thinking allocate(obj.source=list()) is safe is actually not correct. gfortran appears to be mistakenly ignoring finalization of the list() function result when the allocate statement completes. (In the allocatable version, list_final should happen exactly once.)

@francescalus you are right! The Intel compiler ifx-2024.1.0 finalizes list() even in allocate(obj,source=list())  and that causes a segmentation fault. But how to avoid it and keep final?

You can keep the final subroutine just fine when using defined assignment. However, you will need your defined assignment to mimic the logic of when finalization of obj happens. This is your "explicit call to a destructor" as I understand your question. Sometimes the left-hand side in (intrinsic) a=b is finalized, and sometimes it isn't.

I'm noticing very strange differences in behavior of compilers for allocate(obj,source=list()): gfortran-13.1 forgets to finalize list(); ifx-2024.1 ends with a SegFault, since list() was finalized; nagfor-7.1 doesn't forget to finalize list(), but runs without an error (you can ever print val); nvfortran-23.11 doesn't allow allocatable derived type components (?).

A programmer would expect that either obj=list() or allocate(obj,source=list()) would create an instance of list and save it in obj. But, instead, an instance is created, its contents are copied to another instance, and the first instance is finalized. Why are so many steps needed, if it is clear that list() only exists for initialization? Does it mean, that there is practically no way to define a constructor as a function in Fortran? Either assignment should be redefined or an initialization subroutine added and called at the beginning (like call list%init()).

It may be clear to the programmer that list() is used only to construct, with the hope that some form of copy elision happens, but it's worth nothing that list() is explicitly not a constructor. If you want to construct obj you have the option of obj=list(first=head, last=head) (for some head): such constructed values are not finalized (in "corrected" Fortran). As obj is fully default initalized, one has the option also of changing the logic of list_add to handle cases where obj hasn't been "constructed" yet.

Consider also the case allocate(a, b, c, source=x()). x() is evaluated, and finalized, exactly once and the result used to source allocate a, b and c. (F2008)

@francescalus yes, I understand. It's a shame that Fortran doesn't have the ability to define a constructor with complex behavior (not simply assigning the component values like in obj=list(first=head, last=head)). I think, adding an initialization subroutine (and not forgetting to call it before first use) is the simplest solution for my problem. I want to avoid to check if list is initialized every time I add a new element in list_add.

Please check the GCC bugzilla. There were known issues with function result finalization. I think something was fixed in the meantime but perhaps not in all contexts.

Known outstanding finalization bugs are being tracked at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37336 Please check if your issue is already known. Definitely check https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65347 and the comments at the end.

@VladimirFГероямслава thank you. I added a comment to the bug 37336. The bug 65347 doesn't appear to be related to this issue, because gfortran finalizes the temporary instance correctly in the case of assignment obj=list(), but not in the case of allocate with source, which shouldn't differ (like in other compilers).

You can effectively define a constructor function with arbitrary semantics for a derived type by defining a generic interface with the same name as the type.  A correct Fortran compiler will invoke a specific procedure of that generic interface if exactly one of them matches the arguments of a structure constructor that could also be function call, syntactically, and resort to interpreting the structure constructor as a structure constructor if there is no match.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
